# Upgrading bootstrap-sass to 3.3.4 causes loss of glyphicons in bootstrap with Rails. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

Rails 4.2 and boostrap-sass 3.3.4

Everything was working fine in 3.3.3, but after upgrading to 3.3.4, I get 403 forbidden errors when my site tries to access bootstrap's glyphicons fonts.  How do I fix?

My app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss file:

```
$link-color: #00673E;
$brand-primary: #00673E;
@import '*';
@import 'jquery-ui/datepicker';
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

In the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2' #upgrading to 5 makes no difference
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [botched](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/873) the 3.3.4 release, please upgrade to 3.3.4.1. It's the same except for the permissions error fix.